# std::allocator_traits defaults with allocator that has more than one template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, allocator

`std::allocator_traits` works its magic automatically when I provide an STL-style container with an allocator that has a single template parameter but it doesn't when I provide an STL-style container with an allocator that has two template parameters but is otherwise similar.

What do I need to do to tell `std::allocator_traits` how to interact with an allocator that has more than one template parameter? Is it possible to get `std::allocator_traits` to provide reasonable defaults in this case?

As an example, if I take the simple allocator Howard Hinnant provides in [Allocator Boilerplate](https://howardhinnant.github.io/allocator_boilerplate.html) and feed it to a `std::vector<>` then all is well. If I add a dummy `int` parameter to the `allocator` template (and make slight modifications as needed) then I get compiler errors because the compiler couldn't find `rebind`, among other things.

Here's that description in code:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/173c57264137a351

If I have to specialize `std::allocator_traits` myself in this case, is there a way to still get the defaults?

Comment: @bolov I want `std::allocator_traits` to fill in most of the details for me though. Is there any advantage to specializing `std::allocator_traits` vs completing the allocator concept without it?

Comment: @bolov that is not recommended, just provide your own `rebind` in the allocator, see my anwer.

Comment: Start un-commenting some of the things in "Allocator Boilerplate" to fix the compile-time errors.  Of course you'll have to do more than uncomment, you'll have to make whatever you do uncomment consistent with your allocator.  Start with `rebind`.  That may be the only other thing you have to not default, which would be a lot easier than specializing `allocator_traits`.

Comment: @HowardHinnant curiuously, libc++ does compile with the OP's example, whereas libstdc++ doesn't. Do you know/remember what libc++ does for allocators with non-type extra parameters (I glanced at the source, but it seemed like only the regular `Alloc<T, Args...>` was being matched.

Comment: @TemplateRex: My best guess is that libc++'s `vector` doesn't bother calling `rebind`.  The OP's example will likely fail with another container that must call `rebind`.

Comment: @HowardHinnant just checked, with `std::list` instead of `std::vector`, libc++ also doesn't compile. See also [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15225165/819272) where @JonathanWakely explains libstdc++ practice of always going through `rebind`.

Comment: @TemplateRex:  Yeah, libc++ actively rejects the idea that accepting/compiling `vector<int, std::allocator<char>>` is doing the client a favor.  libc++ goes out of its way to notify the client asap if there is a mismatch like this between the allocator and container: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/vector#L479-L480  The motivation for this behavior is because program logic may depend on two independently declared containers having the same type.  And if their type differs only by accidentally misdeclared allocators, best to know at compile time, asap.

Comment: Fwiw, I learned this lesson years before while developing the CodeWarrior std::lib.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Standard only provides a default `rebind` for allocators with multiple template **type** parameters:

> **17.6.3.5 Allocator requirements [allocator.requirements]**
>
> 3 Note A: The member class template `rebind` in the table above is
>   effectively a typedef template. [ Note: In general, if the name
>   `Allocator` is bound to `SomeAllocator<T>`, then
>   `Allocator::rebind<U>::other` is the same type as `SomeAllocator<U>`,
>   where `SomeAllocator<T>::value_type` is `T` and `SomeAllocator<U>::
>   value_type` is `U`. — end note ] If `Allocator` is a class template
>   instantiation of the form `SomeAllocator<T, Args>`, **where `Args` is zero
>   or more type arguments**, and `Allocator` does not supply a `rebind` member
>   template, the standard allocator_traits template uses `SomeAllocator<U, Args>` > in place of `Allocator:: rebind<U>::other` by default. **For
>   allocator types that are not template instantiations of the above
>   form, no default is provided.**

Since you have a non-type (`int`) parameter, there is no default provided. The fix is simple: just add your own rebind to your allocator.

```
template<class T, int I>
class allocator_w_int
{
    // as before

    template<class U>
    struct rebind { using other = allocator_w_int<U, I>; };    
};
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75d830130d1bd453)

As to the rationale of allowing for allocators of the form `Allocator<T, Args...>` but not for allocators of the form `Alloc<T, Ns...>`, one can only guess, but then it would also lead to the plethora of `Alloc<T, Args.., Ns...>` etc. etc.. This is why template-metaprogramming libraries (such as Boost.MPL) always wrap their non-type parameters `N` of type `T` inside things like `integral_constant<T, N>`. This would also be a route for you, by defining

```
template<class T, class Arg>
class allocator_w_int; // leave undefined

template<int N>
using int_ = std::integral_constant<int, N>;

template<class T, int I>
class allocator_w_int<T, int_<I>>
{
    // replace all occurances of I, J --> int_<I>, int_<J>
};
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b31f87ae18654417)